# My chess-board validation program works, but gives an incorrect result

Tags: python, chess

The program is supposed to print True or False depending on whether an arbitrary dictionary stored in a variable meets the criteria for a chess board. The criteria is as follows :
***A valid board will have exactly one black king and exactly one white king. Each player can only have at most 16 pieces, at most 8 pawns, and all pieces must be on a valid space from '1a' to '8h'; that is, a piece can’t be on space '9z'. The piece names begin with either a 'w' or 'b' to represent white or black, followed by 'pawn', 'knight', 'bishop', 'rook', 'queen', or 'king'. This function should detect when a bug has resulted in an improper chess board.***

My program looks like this :

```
board = {'1h': 'bking', '6c': 'wqueen', '2g': 'bbishop',\
'5h': 'bqueen', '3e': 'wking'}
def isValidChessBoard(_board_):
    gen_num=0
    pawn_num=0
    wking_num=0
    bking_num=0
    letters=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
    pieces=['pawn','knight','bishop','rook','king','queen']
    for v in _board_.values():
        gen_num+=1
    if gen_num > 16:
        return False
    for v in _board_.values():
        if v.endswith('pawn'):
            pawn_num+=1
    if pawn_num > 8:
        return False
    for v in _board_.values():
        if v =='wking':
            wking_num+=1
        if v =='bking':
            bking_num+=1
    if wking_num!=1 or bking_num!=1:
        return False
    for k in _board_.keys():
        for i in range(1,9):
            if not k.startswith(str(i)):
                return False
    for k in _board_.keys():
        for i in letters:
            if not k.endswith(i):
                return False
    for v in _board_.values():
        if not v.startswith('b') or v.startswith('w'):
            return False
    for v in _board_.values():
        for i in pieces:
            if not v.endswith(i):
                return False
    return True

print(isValidChessBoard(board))
```

The dictionary seems to meet the given criteria. However, the program prints ''False'' every time I try to run it.

Is there something that I'm missing here ?

Thank you so much in advance, and I apologize if it is too basic or broad of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with loops such as:

```
        for i in range(1,9):
            if not k.startswith(str(i)):
                return False
```

It is insisting that it starts with *all* of these digits, rather than with *any* of them.  The loop can be replaced with:

```
        for i in range(1,9):
            if k.startswith(str(i)):
                break
        else:
            return False
```

Note that the condition is inverted.  If there *is* a match, then it breaks from the loop.  If *no* matches are found, then the `else` block will be executed.  Note the indentation here: the `else` relates to the `for` loop, *not* the `if` block, and will execute if the for loop completed without being broken out of.

There were a couple of places with a similar issue.

You also had one place where parentheses were needed:

```
        if not (v.startswith('b') or v.startswith('w')):
```

because the original without parentheses was equivalent to:

```
        if (not v.startswith('b')) or v.startswith('w'):
```

because `not` has higher operator precedence than binary boolean operators such as `or`.

Putting these fixes together gives:

```
board = {'1h': 'bking', '6c': 'wqueen', '2g': 'bbishop',\
'5h': 'bqueen', '3e': 'wking'}
def isValidChessBoard(_board_):
    gen_num=0
    pawn_num=0
    wking_num=0
    bking_num=0
    letters=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
    pieces=['pawn','knight','bishop','rook','king','queen']
    for v in _board_.values():
        gen_num+=1
    if gen_num > 16:
        return False
    for v in _board_.values():
        if v.endswith('pawn'):
            pawn_num+=1
    if pawn_num > 8:
        return False
    for v in _board_.values():
        if v =='wking':
            wking_num+=1
        if v =='bking':
            bking_num+=1
    if wking_num!=1 or bking_num!=1:
        return False
    for k in _board_.keys():
        for i in range(1,9):
            if k.startswith(str(i)):
                break
        else:
            return False
    for k in _board_.keys():
        for i in letters:
            if k.endswith(i):
                break
        else:
            return False
    for v in _board_.values():
        if not (v.startswith('b') or v.startswith('w')):
            return False
    for v in _board_.values():
        for i in pieces:
            if v.endswith(i):
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True

print(isValidChessBoard(board))
```

Comment: Why doesn't 'if not v/k.ends/startswith(i)' work though ? Or more precisely, why does it give a false value ?

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 The problem is that as it loops over all the digits, it will return False as soon as it finds the first one that it does _not_ start with (of which there are seven), even though there is one of the eight digits that it _does_ start with.

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 Hence the revised version loops through testing for whether it _does_ start with the digit, and it only returns False if none were found.

Comment: @WilliamFrog8 and exactly the same issue where you were testing for the letters, and also the pieces.

Answer (score 3):

If you temporarily replace all `return False` with `raise Exception` then it's very easy to see which part is returning False.

After doing that we can see that this part is the issue:

```
for k in _board_.keys():
    for i in range(1,9):
        if not k.startswith(str(i)):
            return False
```

Not sure what you are trying to do there, I'm guessing you're trying to check that the number of the piece is between 1 and 8? A small change to make that work would be this:

```
for k in _board_.keys():
    for i in range(1,9):
        if k.startswith(str(i)):
            break
    else:
        return False
```

Where we break if we find a match, but if there's no break then we return false. Moving on we find that you've done this mistake in two more places.

We can also see that the logic here isn't so good:

```
if not v.startswith('b') or v.startswith('w'):
```

It should probably be like this:

```
if not v.startswith('b') and not v.startswith('w'):
```

Putting all this together you get this:

```
board = {'1h': 'bking', '6c': 'wqueen', '2g': 'bbishop',\
'5h': 'bqueen', '3e': 'wking'}
def isValidChessBoard(_board_):
    gen_num=0
    pawn_num=0
    wking_num=0
    bking_num=0
    letters=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
    pieces=['pawn','knight','bishop','rook','king','queen']
    for v in _board_.values():
        gen_num+=1
    if gen_num > 16:
        raise Exception
    for v in _board_.values():
        if v.endswith('pawn'):
            pawn_num+=1
    if pawn_num > 8:
        raise Exception
    for v in _board_.values():
        if v =='wking':
            wking_num+=1
        if v =='bking':
            bking_num+=1
    if wking_num!=1 or bking_num!=1:
        raise Exception
    for k in _board_.keys():
        for i in range(1,9):
            if k.startswith(str(i)):
                break
        else:
            raise Exception
    for k in _board_.keys():
        for i in letters:
            if k.endswith(i):
                break
        else:
            raise Exception

    for v in _board_.values():
        if not v.startswith('b') and not v.startswith('w'):
            raise Exception

    for v in _board_.values():
        for i in pieces:
            if v.endswith(i):
                break
        else:
            raise Exception
    return True

print(isValidChessBoard(board))
```

I would suggest leaving the `raise Exception`s until it's done when at which point you just replace them with `return False`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to accomplish, yeah. I still don't really understand what's wrong with it ? The same block gave an error message the first time I ran the program, but that was because i didn't pass the 'i' to the string function. After I did, the program worked but printed False...

Comment: I extended my answer. If you keep getting errors you will need to practice your debuging. Put `print()` statements everywhere or raise `Exceptions` so that you can follow the code trail

Comment: @Mandera The exceptions are a very nice suggestion. I had ploughed through putting different "print" statements before each of the return statements (before arriving at the same conclusion as you regarding the code itself) but a quick search and replace for `raise Exception` is definitely quicker and easier.

Comment: @alaniwi Haha, I was doing the same thing, but thank you!